# Pass the number of copies required from an internal website to the printer

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, printing

Is it possible to set the number of copies to print from a website using something like JavaScript?

We have a situation where if we are sending out 10 boxes then we need to print 10 documents. The number is stored in a database and the user will find this information by searching on the order number. The idea is when they press print the webpage passes the number of copies required.

I have read some old posts that say no on here but
I was wondering if there was now a solution to this problem. The closest I have seen is Google Chrome Kiosk mode but this only seems to print 1 copy.

If not possible in HTML/JavaScript then I am happy to look into alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

I switched to PHP and used the `exec()` function. This allowed me to specify my criteria.

Answer (score -1):

I have not tried this, maybe it could work.

Define an onafterprint function and repeat printing the next pages, using Google Chrome Kiosk mode for printing without print dialog.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Printing

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onafterprint

Answer (score -1):

Alternative idea: use the server to generate a pdf containing the same document with x copies and then print the single pdf outputting x copies.